# how to pass environment variables stored in .env file to node script running from shell script?

Tags: node.js, shell, environment-variables, dotenv

I am trying to run a node js script from shell script in MAC.

```
#!bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/node /opt/myprojects/instabot/index.js
```

It works fine, but the problem is when I try to read environment variables, they show as `undefined`, I am passing environment variables using .env file in node js script using dotenv package (I can read the environment variables correctly when I run it directly using `node index.js`)

using this to configure dotenv package `require('dotenv').config()`

.env file is in `KEY=VALUE` format

Answer (score 0):

If possible try to move that bash file inside the same directory as the index.js file it will work. Otherwise, you need to `export` env variables and you can do this permanently by editing your .bashrc file or temporarily using commands like `export foo=bar`

Comment: I wish to read the variables from .env file only so I can use the same file when I run the program directly with node command, and cannot put it in the same folder due to some structure related issues. can you help with that?

Comment: yes sure @VaibhavVerma. As I mentioned in the suggested solution you can set up these env variables temporarily. Here is how your bash file should look if you want to access your env variable name `SOME_KEY` which has a value `some val` Contents of bash file may look like this : `#!/usr/bash
echo "hi"
echo "setting up env variables temporarily"
export SOME_KEY=some val
/Users/..YOUR_PROJECT_PATH_TO_NODE/node /Users/..YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/glob index.js`

Comment: So the idea is to copy variables from the .env file and paste them in a bash file and export them for the bash file to execute. Hope this solves the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You should do in this way encoding in `utf-8` to work `.env` file:

```js
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs=require('fs');
const configPath = path.join(__dirname, 'config.env');
dotenv.config({ path: configPath });
fs.readFileSync(configPath, 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Env variables need to be injected. The manual way to do this would be

```
USER_ID=239482 USER_KEY=foobar node index.js
```

But as you already have a .env file and doing this everytime is painful. Environment variables from .env need to be injected. The bash script below does that, make sure the bash script is at the same level as index.js in the directory heirarchy. And when you want to start the project just the run the script .

```
#!bin/bash

set -euo pipefail
scriptPath="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" || true ; pwd -P)"

fail() {
    echo "ERROR: $*" > /dev/stderr
    exit 1
}

insertDotEnvVars() {
    insertEnvFileAndRun "$scriptPath/.env" "$@"
}

insertEnvFileAndRun() {
    local envFile="$1"; shift
    [[ -f "$envFile" ]] || fail "${envFile} env file not found"
    env $(cat $envFile | sed 's/\r$//'| xargs) "$@"
}

echo "Starting app"

insertDotEnvVars /usr/local/bin/node "$scriptPath/index.js"
```

Now if you save this script as say `run.sh` , you can easily run by `./run.sh` or update your package.json to use this bash file for start. Then you can just `npm run start`

Comment: Whoops, i guess i'll leave this here but just saw this is two year old question.